# mongoose aggregate: same $match for two different $group

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I would like to perform two aggregate functions using the same filter. I could do the following:

```
// create first aggregate query
var query1 = myModel.aggregate([
    { $match: myMatchCriteria }, 
    { $group1: myGroupCriteria1 }
]);

// create second aggregate query
var query2 = myModel.aggregate([
    { $match: myMatchCriteria }, 
    { $group2: myGroupCriteria2 }
]);

// execute both queries
query1.exec(myCallback);
query2.exec(myCallback);
```

But it does not seem optimal: as I understand, $match uses find() under the hood, so I would query my db twice for the same output.

It there some way to "save" the find() results and then apply the aggregates to them? Something like:

```
var myFilteredDocuments = myModel.find(myMatchCriteria);

var query1 = myFilteredDocuments.aggregate([{ $group2: myGroupCriteria1 }]),
    query2 = myFilteredDocuments.aggregate([{ $group2: myGroupCriteria2 }])
```

Comment: try `$out` pipeline stage. it should save your result into specified collection.

Comment: There will be new operator $facet that will cover the problem  in the upcoming version

Comment: @Saleem thanks it should do the trick for now. To complete @profesor79 comment, I found some information about `$facet` [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23654). It will completely answer my needs.